# Ontology inconsistence with Man and Woman as Father and Mother on Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

Say we have these classes, Man and Woman, with Father and Mother as subclasses respectively. Man is Disjoint with Woman.

There is an object property called **hasDaughter**, with Father and Mother as domain, and Daughter as range.

Now when I try to run the reasoner I get an inconsistency error with this explanation:

```
Man DisjointWith Woman
John hasDaughter Annie
Father SubClassOf Man
hasDaughter Domain Mother
Mother SubClassOf Woman
hasDaughter Domain Father
```

Now I know this is because since both Father and Mother can have a daughter, the reasoner thinks since X has a daughter X can be either a Father or a Mother, or both, and since they are disjoint something must be wrong.

What could I do to solve this? The idea is to have both Father and Mother classes, not just one Parent class, I know that would make things easier.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate your classes such that `man`, `woman` and `father`, `mother` are separated. So you need to have two branches in your ontology:

```
Person
    Man
    Woman
Role
    Mother
    Father
    Daughter
    ....
```

You can make `Man` and `Woman` disjoint. And then you can say `A Man hasRole Father` and `A Woman hasRole Mother`, and other modelling decisions.

Or you can go the other way, you can keep your modelling and just define `hasFather` and `hasMother` instead of `hasDaughter` and then put domain and range restrictions on these new properties.

Comment: In your role model, how are you defining the domain of hasDaughter?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. In the simplest way, you can say domain is Man going to range Woman. It depends how detailed you define this model.

Comment: I'm not seeing how you solved the OP's issue.  He needs to express that `John hasDaughter Annie.`    Without inferring that `john` is both a `Mother` AND a `father`, (nor `man` and `woman`).  I ready to be amazed, but I'm missing something!

Answer (score 2):

> *Now I know this is because since both Father and Mother can have a daughter, the reasoner thinks since X has a daughter X can be either a
>   Father or a Mother, or both, and since they are disjoint something
>   must be wrong.*

When you declare multiple domains on a property, the interpretation is not disjunction (e.g., "either a Father or a Mother"), but conjunction (i.e., "is both a Father and a Mother").  If you say

```
p domain A
p domain B
```

and then assert

```
x p y
```

a reasoner will infer that x is both an A and a B.  If you want disjunction, then you need to make the union class the domain.  I.e., you need to do:

```
hasDaugher domain (Father or Mother)
```

Then when you have an assertion

```
John hasDaughter Annie
```

the reasoner will infer

```
John is a (Father or Mother)
```

which is consistent with your other assertions.